# Como pegar um valor de arraylist de string, para um array de File

Tags: arquivo, arraylist

Eu estou com um trabalho para fazer, para faze-lo, eu preciso passar uma informação de um array composto por strings(que são os paths) para um array de files para que se faça a leitura desses paths, tentei pegar o valor diretamente dessas duas formas

```
leitura.add(System.out.println(Arrays.toString(diretorioRaiz.toArray()) ));// 1 tentativa
leitura.addAll(diretorioRaiz.get(0));//2 tentativa
```

Eu fiz isso, mas não consegui, tentei também criar uma variável do tipo string para "segurar" o valor e depois usar ela para pegar o valor

```
static  String myString = new String ();
myString = diretorioRaiz.get(0);
leitura.add(myString);
```

Answer (score 1):

Se você tem um `ArrayList` de strings, basta percorrê-lo e utilizar a "string da vez" para criar um novo [**`File(String pathname)`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.lang.String%29):

```java
ArrayList<String> arrayListDeStrings = ...

// Populando 'arrayListDeStrings'.


ArrayList<File> arrayListDeFiles = new ArrayList<>();

for(String stringDaVez : arrayListDeStrings)
   arrayListDeFiles.add(new File(stringDaVez));
```

Answer (score 1):

Em Java 8 você pode fazer assim:

```
strList.stream().map(File::new).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Exemplo mais completo:

```
List<String> strList = new ArrayList<>();
//adiciona itens em strList
List<File> fileList = strList.stream().map(File::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

## Explicação

Primeiro, `strList.stream()` gera um `Stream` a partir da lista. `Stream` é a representação de uma coleção de elementos que suporta operações em todo o conjunto. É algo parecido com SQL ou jQuery.

Depois, o método `map` do `Stream` permite aplicar uma operação em todo o conjunto. A operação que queremos realizar é converter uma `String` para um `File`. Fazemos isso passando um método que faz a conversão de um único elementos e o método `map` se encarrega de aplicar a todos os elementos.

Poderíamos usar um método lambda da seguinte forma:

```
List<File> fileList = strList.stream().map(s -> new File(s)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Entretanto, podemos simplificar isso passando a referência para o construtor de `File` que recebe uma `String`.

Note que poderíamos passar qualquer método que receba uma `String` como parâmetro e retorne um `File` e obteríamos o mesmo resultado.

Finalmente, pegamos o resultado do processamento de `map`, que transformou um `Stream` de `String` em um `Stream` de `File` e coletamos em uma lista de `File usando o método`collect` e informando que tipo de estrutura de dados nós desejamos.

## Tem certeza que você quer `File`?

Desde o Java 7 é recomendável usar a nova API de entrada e saída (NIO ou New IO). Portanto, ao invés de usar `File` você deveria estar usando [`Path`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html).

Exemplo:

```
List<Path> fileList = strList.stream().map(Paths::get).collect(Collectors.toList());
```